# Merging Multiple Like lines into one line using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Newby here. I've been slowly teaching myself to code in SQL Server and this board has been an invaluable tool for my learning so far. However, I haven't been able to wrap my brain around my current problem.

I have a large ascii text file delimited by pipes. Every line starts with a record type, but the numbers of each record type can vary. I have lines that start with `ENCUD|` and then a field title, and then a field value.

For example:

```
ENCUD|CUSTOMER NAME|Smith
```

and then the next several lines also start with `ENCUD|` but different field titles and field values.

These `ENCUD` values occur throughout the file, with other records in between where they occur.

What I'm looking to do is to combine all values that start with "ENCUD|" and are grouped together, into one line.  I.e.

```
ENCUD|CUSTOMER NAME|Smith
ENCUD|CUSTOMER NUMBER|12345
ENCUD|CUSTOMER ID|6789
NEW RECORD|...
NEW RECORD|...
NEW RECORD|...
ENCUD|CUSTOMER NAME|Jones
ENCUD|CUSTOMER NUMBER|23456
ENCUD|CUSTOMER ID|9876
```

What I want to have happen is:

```
ENCUD|CUSTOMER INFORMATION|Smith|12345|6789
NEW RECORD|...
NEW RECORD|...
NEW RECORD|...
ENCUD|CUSTOMER INFORMATION|Jones|23456|9876
```

Is there a way to do this within SQL Server?

Comment: It is most likely possible to do this with SQL Server, but there are other tools better for the job.

Comment: Depending on the tool, I'm all ears.

Comment: What version of sql server please? (features vary version to version, it is a good idea to include that info in your questions). Given that this ascii data is in a file outside of SQL Server couldn't you use python or any similar language with strong text handling?

Comment: Yeah, not sure why you'd want to do this with SQL and not put the data into a tabular structure, with the distinct field titles as the column names.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012.  Eventually these files get loaded into Oracle tables, but this manipulation needs to be done before it is loaded into Oracle.  I'm willing to use other tools if anyone here can point me in the right direction for the tool that would be easiest to do this with.  I just have easy access to SQL server and I'm not as familiar with Python

Comment: @thoopy - I would use C# or python because that is what I'm familar with. There are a ton of tools to help you parse and process text files...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would parse the text you have in C# to derive your desired output. Keep in mind there are many ways of doing this!

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");    //read the file in
var newLines = new List<string>();                  //stores the desired output
var prevENCUD = false;                              //detects start of new ENCUD records

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("ENCUD"))
    {
        if (!prevENCUD) //add a new line
        {
            newLines.Add(line);
        }
        else            //splits the line and adds just the customer number
        {
            var fields = line.Split('|');
            newLines[newLines.Count - 1] = newLines[newLines.Count - 1] + "|" + fields[fields.Length - 1];
        }

        prevENCUD = true;
    }
    else  //adds any record that isn't ENCUD
    {
        newLines.Add(line);
        prevENCUD = false;
    }
}
```